# OpenLDAP 2.6 のトランザクションログの設定について

Tags: ldap

OpenLDAP を 2.4 から 2.6 へ上げようとしています。

2.4であったトランザクションログの設定値

```
olcDbConfig: set_lg_regionmax
olcDbConfig: set_lg_bsize
olcDbConfig: set_flags
```

この設定値が2.6になり、なくなったようです。

olcDbConfigの代わりにできたolcMdbConfigに相当する設定値がないのですが、同じようなログの仕組みがないとログファイルがパンクすると考えます。

どのように設定すればよろしいでしょうかご存知の方ご教示願います。
設定値がないので、現在は未設定で動かしています。